# Double accusative in abdico (abdicare cibum aliquem)

Tags: verbs

In several dictionaries I encountered under *abdico* (1st conj.):

> Abdicare cibum aliquem (Plin.) to prohibit the use of any meat as not good ([Thomas Thomasius dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=WQJnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP16&lpg=PP16&dq=Abdicare%20cibum%20aliquem&source=bl&ots=AQm51NS1eg&sig=ACfU3U2zuD51uOre_galGolUgr3jKxHNWA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif85bixLTvAhWHAWMBHe_7CDkQ6AEwBXoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=Abdicare%20cibum%20aliquem&f=false))

> Abdicare cibum aliqem (Plin. 20, 9) to forbid the use of it ([Robert Ainsworth dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=1zZLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP9&lpg=PP9&dq=Abdicare%20cibum%20aliquem&source=bl&ots=fofU5K4fAL&sig=ACfU3U3GsgwJCfr2aO4MlL4iU8WhnpeVmw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG5eKpyLTvAhWSsRQKHdv0Cf44ChDoATAAegQIBRAD#v=onepage&q=Abdicare%20cibum%20aliquem&f=false))

I looked up the reference and I found (Probably the correct one, but not sure):

> Democritus in totum ea abdicavit in cibis propter inflationes (Nat. 20, 9)

I assume, maybe wrongly so, that *ea* matches *aliquem* in the dictionaries formula, but *in cibis* here seems to be adverbial, specifically not the expected accusative.

So all in, I can't reconcile those. Can *abdico* be used with double acc construction? if so what does it mean?

Comment: [Searching for *abdic-* and *cib-* close to each other](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23abdic+%7E+%23cib) in a classical corpus gives two hits, only one in Pliny, and it is the one you found. [Other hits for *abdic-* in Pliny](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23abdic+%5Bplinsen%5D) seem to contain no double accusatives, based on a very quick look. Peculiar...

Comment: Not sure where “prohibit” comes from, by the way. Democritus *rejected* [the use in food of] turnips.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, thanks for this remark. We have to keep in mind those dictionaries are quite old from 17th century or so. Maybe back then *prohibit* had also the sense of *reject*. don't know.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. Why do you say that? Besides the two dictionary entries cited above, [_Lewis and Short_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=Abdicare&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=abdico2-contents) list _to forbid_ as an accepted meaning. Isn't that  synonymous with *to prohibit*? Are you speaking about the broader context of the text?

Comment: @ExpeditoBipes No, that's for *abdicere*, not *abdicare*. (And anyway it is “to forbid by an unfavorable omen” – I'm not sure what that means, but it does seem a bit melodramatic for discouraging the consumption of turnips on account of flatulence ;-))

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. I see what you mean. I'll update my answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *[aliquem](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=aliquem)* can be used both as a substantive as well as an adjective, so in the expression "*Abdicare cibum aliqem*", it should be taken as an adjective:

> To reject some food.

Therefore, the only formula present in this example is a verb form (in this case, the infinitve *abdicare*) and a direct object (*cibum aliqem*). There is no double accusative.

I agree with your reading that *in cibis* serves as an adverbial phrase. I understand the sentence as follows:

> Democritus entirely rejected them as a food because of flatulence.

Comment: Haha. Thank you. So the formula just meant to show *abdicare* works with food.

Comment: And it now occurs to me, that maybe the reason to place *aliquem* after *cibum* to stress it is merely adj. usage. (which, interestingly enough merely confused me. as for some reason it is more natural to me to see adjectival *aliqui* before the noun. (like *hic*, or other formula like *de aliqua re*))

Comment: @d_e. According to _Bradley's Arnold Latin Prose Composition_, "Adjectives, when used as attributes, are oftener than not placed after the noun with which they agree; but demonstrative and interrogative pronouns, numerals, and adjectives denoting size or quantity come before the noun they qualify." I'm not sure about the word order, but perhaps it was meant to convey a meaning such as "To prohibit food of some/any kind," as opposed to the more deterministic "To prohibit some food".

Comment: @Expredito Bipes, maybe. But I think it further suggests my idea: Because of the ambiguity of *aliquem*, placing it before *cibum* would suggest *aliquem* as the pronoun, hence the decision was taken to put it after *cibum* however being less conventional.